# Why ng-repeat does not work in this AngularJs 1.5.x component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="helloall">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello All</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <item data="name" ng-repeat="name in names"></item>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('helloall', []);
function componentCtrl(){
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.otherNames  = [{last: "John", first: "Doe"}, {last: "Mary", first: "Jane"}];
}

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{family: "asdf", first: "test"}, {family: "qwerty", first: "test2"}]
});

angular.module('helloall').component('item', {
   controller: componentCtrl,
   templateUrl: 'item.html',
   bindings: {
     data: '='
   }
});
```

And here is the item.html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.otherNames">
  Name: {{name.last}}
</tr>
<br>
{{$ctrl.data.first}}
{{$ctrl.data.family}}
<br>
```

And here is the output:

Other Last Name: 

test asdf

Other Last Name:

test2 qwerty

I wonder why ng-repeat in the following section does not work.:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.otherNames">
      Name: {{name.last}}
</tr>
```

{{name}} or {{name.last}} outputs nothing.

When I do {{$ctrl.otherNames}} then the output shows the content of "otherNames"

Why?

View the issue in Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/X3gKdZUJIVbNcBlgYfkW?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `tr` tags in `item.html` to `div` will make it work.

Additionally you can just add `table` tags around the `tr`'s and then `td`'s.

https://plnkr.co/edit/U0XjMUkixs9s1RsswWVK

Comment: It works.  So the problem is html, not angularjs ng-repeat in the component.

Comment: When I do the following:
<tr ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.otherNames">
  <td>Other Last Name: {{name.last}} </td>
</tr>
It does not work until I add table tag.  How come in plain html, I can do <tr><td></td><tr> and that shows data?  However when using with Angularjs, then it requires to have table tag to work?